# How to correctly split column by delimiter?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split

I have to split column `game` by the delimiter `-`

```
df: 
                                                 game                               home_team                       away_team
0                         Bordj Menail – Hamra Annaba                            Bordj Menail                    Hamra Annaba
1                                  CA Batna – US Souf                                CA Batna                         US Souf
2                                     Eulma – Ouargla                                   Eulma                         Ouargla
1860                            Bella Vista – Miramar                             Bella Vista                         Miramar
1861                 U.A.N.L.- Tigres W – Club Leon W                      U.A.N.L.- Tigres W                     Club Leon W
1862                               Queretaro – Toluca                               Queretaro                          Toluca
0                           Sport Recife - Imperatriz               Sport Recife - Imperatriz                            None
1                                    ABC - America RN                        ABC - America RN                            None
2                           Frei Paulistano - Nautico               Frei Paulistano - Nautico                            None
3                             Botafogo PB - Confianca                 Botafogo PB - Confianca                            None
```

I am trying

```
df[team_cols] = df['game'].str.split(' – ', expand=True, n=1)
```

But I am only able to do so partially as above

When I look it via excel, I can see that the delimiter "appears" differently

e.g.

```
Sport Recife â Sport Recife ## Here delimiter is a special character?
Bordj Menail – Hamra Annaba
```

How can I split the values? And what is this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unclear what you mean, but I would do this this way

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'game': [
        'Bordj Menail – Hamra Annaba',
        'CA Batna – US Souf',
        'Eulma – Ouargla',
        'Bella Vista – Miramar',
        'U.A.N.L.- Tigres W – Club Leon W',
        'Queretaro – Toluca',
        'Sport Recife - Imperatriz',
        'ABC - America RN',
        'Frei Paulistano - Nautico',
        'Botafogo PB - Confianca'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Split the game column
pattern = r'\s*[-–â]\s*'
team_cols = ['home_team', 'away_team']
df[team_cols] = df['game'].str.split(pattern, expand=True, n=1)

# Print the result
print(df)
```

which gives

```
                               game        home_team               away_team
0       Bordj Menail – Hamra Annaba     Bordj Menail            Hamra Annaba
1                CA Batna – US Souf         CA Batna                 US Souf
2                   Eulma – Ouargla            Eulma                 Ouargla
3             Bella Vista – Miramar      Bella Vista                 Miramar
4  U.A.N.L.- Tigres W – Club Leon W         U.A.N.L.  Tigres W – Club Leon W
5                Queretaro – Toluca        Queretaro                  Toluca
6         Sport Recife - Imperatriz     Sport Recife              Imperatriz
7                  ABC - America RN              ABC              America RN
8         Frei Paulistano - Nautico  Frei Paulistano                 Nautico
9           Botafogo PB - Confianca      Botafogo PB               Confianca
```

Comment: What is this special character `â` and why does it appear differently in excel and when I look at it on other platform like pycharm for example?